# jQuery: this.attr() not a function?

Tags: jquery, object, attributes

I'm not quite sure if I'm not using this in the correct scope or what, but I have a script that basically captures a link click and causes the page to fade out before going to the linked page. However, if the link is a JavaScript *onclick*, the script fails.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    pageObj = {
        init: function(){
            $("body").fadeTo("slow", 1);
        },
        redirectPage: function(redirect){
            window.location = redirect;
        },
        linkLoad: function(location){
            $("body").fadeOut(1000, this.redirectPage(location));
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        pageObj.init();

        $("a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.attr('onclick') !== undefined) {
                eval(this.attr('onclick').val());
            } else {
                var location = this.href;
                pageObj.linkLoad(location);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to do a check to see if the link has the *onclick* attribute, and then call the *onclick* function if it exists. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While Diodeus is correct that you need to wrap `this` in a jQuery collection before using `attr()` (it's a method of a jQuery collection, not of an `HTMLElement`), you can just as well skip `attr()`.

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    var location;
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($.isFunction(this.onclick)) {
        this.onclick.call(this, e);
    } else {
        location = this.href;
        pageObj.linkLoad(location);
    }
});
```

Note that I used the property (when an HTML document loads, attributes are usually preloaded into properties, with `on_______` attributes being preloaded as methods. Also note that I used `this.onclick.call()` rather than `eval()`, setting the correct `this` for `onclick` methods, and ensuring access to the event object as an argument.

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. I understand that call() would be safer to use than eval(), as well, correct?

Answer (score 113):

Use: `$(this).attr` instead of `this.attr`

This forces it into the context of jQuery.

Comment: I would have thought this would work, too, however, i get `$(this).attr("onclick").val is not a function` using it.

Comment: You don't need .val() in this case.