# Loop through Drop Down Option and read its attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am looping through drop down option and checking attribute.
if attribute match than counter is increase. At the end i show counter as alert.
This is my code but some how its not working dont know why

```
        var count= 0;
        $('.mydropdown option').each(function () {
            var level = this.attr("myattr");
            if (level == "0") {
                count++;
            }
        });
            alert(count);
        }
```

Comment: @satpal, OP knows how to get attribute(.attr) from an element, he's probably asking what's wrong with his code. why `this.attr('key')` making problem here..

Comment: A good read for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633270/difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, He is mixing vaniaal js and jquery

Comment: And this too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164652/jquery-this-attr-not-a-function

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a plain javascript object, it does not contain a function called `.attr()`

Try,

```
 var level = $(this).attr("myattr");
```

Just convert the `this` reference into a jquery object and invoke `.attr()` over it

Comment: even after changing its not working

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Show your code in jsfiddle.net  I'll check..